# A holomorphic function $f$ has an essential singularity in $0$ iff $\exists(z_k)_k$ s.t. $z_k\to 0$ and $|z_k^mf(z_k)|\to\infty$ for all $m$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function $\Rightarrow$ $f$ has an essential singularity in $0$ if and only if $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}:\exists (z_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ such that $z_k\to 0$ and $\left|z_k^mf(z_k)\right|\to\infty$ for $k\to\infty$.

---

Since $f$ is holomorphic $$f\equiv\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_kz^k$$ for some $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$. Moreover, $f$ has an essential singularity in $0$ if and only if $\exists\left(k_j\right)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $k_j\to -\infty$ and $a_{k_j}\ne 0$.

How does one prove the theorem given these facts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one direction, if $f$ has a removable singularity or a pole of order $k$ in $0$, what can you say about the function $z\mapsto z^m f(z)$ for large enough $m$?

For the other direction, note that if $f$ has an essential singularity in $0$, then so has $z \mapsto z^m f(z)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Appeal to the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem if necessary.

Comment: If $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$, then doesn't that automatically mean the negative-power part of the Laurent series can be written as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^{-n}$$ with $a_n \not = 0$ for infinitely many $n$? If so, then perhaps the conclusion can be worked from that, using limits then converting to the sequential definition.

Comment: Yes, you can work from that. You can use that an entire function that grows at most as fast as some power of $\lvert z\rvert$ must be a polynomial, and from that obtain the conclusion. But I think the characterisation of isolated singularities in terms of growth-rate is more direct. If bounded, the singularity is removable, if it grows at most as fast as $\lvert z-a\rvert^{-k}$, it's a pole of order $\leqslant k$.

Comment: ($\Leftarrow$): If $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$, then $$z^mf(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^{k+m}$$ If $0$ is a pole of order $m$, then $$z^mf(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^{k+m}+\sum_{k=1}^m a_{-k}z^{-k+m}$$

$(\Rightarrow)$: I haven't heard about the mentioned theorem until now. I'm still unsure how I can obtain $(z_k)_k$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d All you really need is that $z\mapsto z^m f(z)$ doesn't have a removable singularity in $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's clear for me, that $z\mapsto z^mf(z)$ must have an essential singularity in $0$. Maybe the solution is now obvious, but I still can't see how this helps to prove the statement.

Comment: @0xbadf00d If it has an essential singularity, can it be bounded in any punctured neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, since $0$ is not a removable singularity in $f$.

Comment: Good, @0xbadf00d. And that the function (let's call it $g$) is unbounded on every punctured neighbourhood of $0$ means we can find a sequence $z_k \to 0$ such that $\lvert g(z_k)\rvert \to \infty$, doesn't it?

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. What about the other direction?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You basically have the other direction in your comment above. If the singularity is a pole or removable, then $z^mf(z)$ has a removable singularity in $0$ for all large enough $m$, so the such a sequence can only exist for finitely many $m$.

Comment: @DanielFischer $f$ has a removable singularity in $z_0$ iff the principal part of $f$ is trivial. So, could you explain "large enough" in more detail?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If the singularity is removable, "large enough" means $m \geqslant 0$. If a pole of order $k$, it means $m \geqslant k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Seems quite obvious from my comment above. Thanks again.